# How do you pass data from view to view with location.href?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two `.cshtml` files. One is my login page, which is `login.cshtml` and I have the main page, which is `_Layout.cshtml`. Currently when I login with proper information, it sends me to the home page. The code for that check is...

```
 $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        //alert("NOW");
        e.preventDefault();


        var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
        var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
        var json = { Email: email, Password: password };
        var string = JSON.stringify(json);

        //var url = 'http://www.uBuildRewards.api/api/Users/GetValid';
        //url = 'proxy.php?url=' + url;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://uBuildRewards.api/api/Users/Post',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: string,
            success: function (data) {
                var doug = data.FirstName; //Playing Around
                var june = data.LastName; //Playing Around
                location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';

                @*location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")?doug=data.FirstName';*@ //Playing Around

            },
            error: function (error) { alert('Wrong Info'); }
        });
    });
```

But now what I want to do is transfer the "data" that is recieved from the login to the layout page so I am able to display Hello, (Name of Whoever Logged In) and show his or her current email address. Like place the name and email of whoever logged in, within the `(Name Here)` and `(Email Here)` spots. I have tried many things, but none of which worked. The stuff I played around with are labeled with `//Playing Around` above.

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-logged-in">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="user-name" id="firstName">(Name Here) <span class="text-muted f9">admin</span></div>
                    <div class="user-email" id="userEmail">(Email Here)</div>
                    <div class="user-actions">
                        <a class="m-r-5" href="">settings</a> <a href="/first/login">logout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I greatly appreciate all your help in advance!

Comment: you should really consider watching this tutorial on how mvc works http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4-building

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but I'm guessing what you could do is create a form using JS/jQuery, and submit data to the layout? So you could add this to the success callback.

```
var $form=$(document.createElement('form')).css({display:'none'}).attr("method","POST").attr("action",'@Url.Action("Index", "Home")');
var $name=$(document.createElement('input')).attr('name','FIRST NAME HERE').val(data.FirstName);
var $email=$(document.createElement('input')).attr('name','EMAIL').val(data.Email);
$form.append($name).append($email);
$("body").append($form);
$form.submit();
```

Something along the lines of this could be one solution. Not sure if this is the best way of doing it.